# What should I consider in deploying iPads?

Tags: ipad, security

I have built a web-based process management system for the company I work for. It manages all aspects of the business: estimates, clients, scheduling, accounting, work-orders, etc. The business has 3-5 service crews that receive a stack of printed work orders (printed from this system) that they go out and complete over the course of their day. At the end of the day, the stack of work orders is given back to the office to transfer the completed work order details into the system.

The boss now wants to loose the paper printouts for work orders and instead put an iPad in each service vehicle. The idea is that the service person will log into our web based process management system, and work off of a list of work orders on the site. There are a bunch of benefits to this, which I don't think I need to list.

My question is, do I need to have any extra concerns about having iPads out in the field logging into the web-based system to complete work orders? Anything extra I should be doing? I can't help think that this is no different than a laptop logging into the system (which is already happening) - however the difference is that the iPads will be using a cellular connection, not a wifi connection. Should I be taking any extra steps to manage the iPad connections beyond the normal security steps I already have in place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that if people leave the iPads logged in and they're stolen then an attacker (or, more realistically, a random thief) would have access to your application and the data. This is easily countermeasured by having a password on the iPad and having the cookies expire after a set amount of inactivity (a feature you probably have already).

Additionally, it might be worthwhile to install tracking software on the iPads just in case of theft.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We ended up going with iPhone 5's instead of iPads. We have also signed up for a monitoring service so I can, remotely, control most aspects of the phones. For a lost phone, I can geolocate it and lock it - or, if needed, wipe the phone clean.